# What is this kanji?眞+頁

Tags: kanji

So I came across a kanji I can't seem to find in any online dictionary.
It's basically the following two characters stuck together 眞頁 (I'm reading a physical book, so can't copy paste it), and is followed by 末.
After trawling through jisho, the closest I've found is 顛末, which would make sense in context, but definitely isn't the same.

Comment: The character on the left is an old way of writing 真. I've got no idea for the character on the right. This may be relevant to you: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1350949868

Comment: Thanks for the link, found what I needed here: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10109439580 
So it actually is just 顛末

Comment: Just for reference https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A1%9B-577435

Comment: For what it's worth, the [beta version of Jisho does list 顚末](http://beta.jisho.org/search/%E9%A1%9A%E6%9C%AB) (see "other forms")

Comment: Ah, blessed be [Google Translate's handwriting input](http://i.imgur.com/OwhUCqV.png)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess seems to be right.  [顚](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A1%9B) is considered to be an 異体字 (variant form) for 顛. There is no difference in meaning.

Comment: Compare: 真⇔眞, 慎⇔愼, 鎮⇔鎭, 填⇔塡, 槙⇔槇, 鷏⇔鷆, 顛⇔顚

Comment: In addition, there's a bit complicated matter that the official orthography standard that has purged 眞/愼 in favor of 真/慎, in turn gives preference to 顚 over 顛 for printing.